# Использование паттерна Command

Tags: веб-программирование, mvc, java, шаблоны-проектирования

Реализую MVC на Java.
Есть у меня сервлет-контроллер. К нему обращаются jsp. Он выполняет отведенную ему роль и перенаправляет на какую-то страницу.
Каждому запросу `HTTPServletRequest request` ставится в соответствие команда, логика которой сосредоточена в методе `execute()` класса, имплементящего интерфейс `Command`

```
public interface Command {
String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response);}
```

Шаблон Command. Соответствие определяется по значению параметра "command" запроса.
Контроллер в `doGet/doPost` обращается к методу `getCommand(HTTPServletRequest request)` вспомогательного класса `RequestHelper`, реализованного как Singletone.
Вот он:

```
public class RequestHelper {
private static RequestHelper instance = null;
HashMap<String, Command> commands = new HashMap<String, Command>();

private RequestHelper() {
    super();
    commands.put("login", new LoginCommand());
    commands.put("logout", new LogoutCommand());
    commands.put("chooseTrip", new ChooseTripCommand());
    commands.put("order", new OrderCommand());
    commands.put("updateOrders", new UpdateOrdersCommand());

}

public static RequestHelper getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new RequestHelper();
    }
    return instance;
}

public Command getCommand(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Command command;
    command = commands.get(request.getParameter("command"));
    if (command == null) {
        command = new NoCommand();
    }
    return command;
}
```

Вопрос в следующем: нормально ли с точки зрения соответствия шаблонам проектирования и вообще, вызывать метод `execute()` объекта `OneCommand` напрямую из метода другого команда (TwoCommand), естественно при этом либо создавая новый объект при каждом вызове метода этого самого TwoCommand, либо сделав его полем.
**Словом, комманд вызывает комманд, это нормально?**

Comment: Просто из интереса... не могли бы вы привести пример такой команды, которая вызывает другую?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Словом, комманд вызывает комманд, это нормально?

нормально, можно даже [шаблон](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) применить

p.s.

`public Command getCommand(HttpServletRequest request) {` - здесь название метода не совсем корректное. get/set используются для того чтоб считывать и сетить значения полей. в вашем случае более уместно название метода read или parse

`command = new NoCommand();` - не вижу смысла создавать каждый раз обьект `NoCommand`. достаточно будет и одного. можно сделать один экземпляр по аналогии с `Collections.EMPTY_LIST, EMPTY_SET, EMPTY_MAP`:

```
interface Command
{
    String NO_RESULT = null ; // изменить на нужное
    Command NO_ACTION = new Command ()
    {
        @ Override
        public String execute ( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
        {
            return NO_RESULT ;
        }
    } ;

    String execute ( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Еще пару слов про шаблон

Здесь уместно также применение и [Chain of responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern). Основная идея шаблона в том, что действие сложной команды может быть распределено между различными исполнителями, и каждый шаг действия знает лишь о следующем шаге, но не о том, кто будет его выполнять. В этом случае как разу уместен вызов команды из команды, по цепочке.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Command getCommand(HttpServletRequest request) {
Command command;
command = commands.get(request.getParameter("command"));
if (command == null) {
    command = new NoCommand();
}
return command;
```

}

Зачем брать параметр по "command"? Правильнее использовать проверку параметра на null. И все команды определить в enum.

```
public enum ActionTypes {
    LOGIN, MESSAGE, LOGOUT, KICK;
}

public ICommand getCommand(HttpServletRequest request) {
    ICommand command = null;
    for (Enum<ActionTypes> type : ActionTypes.values()) {
        String action = typesToString(type);
        String param = request.getParameter(action);
        if (param != null) {
            command = commands.get(action);
        }
    }
    return command;
}
```

Т.е. проверяя наличие параметра, брать из мапы нужный экшн. Если появится новый элемент на сайте, то банально вписываем одну строчку в enum и всё.

Comment: еще лучше будет если enum добавить конструктор с параметром в качестве которого выступает инстанс обработчика и геттер для него. это будет выглядеть так:
    LOGIN (new LoginCommand()), 
    ...
    KICK (new KickCommand());

реализация:

    private Command command;
    private ActionTypes (ICommand command) {this.command = command}
    public Command getCommand() {return command;}

Comment: или даже так:

    public enum ActionTypes extends Command {
    ... код из примера выше без геттера ...

       public String execute ( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response )
       {
           return command.execute(request, response) ;
       }
    }